# Organize the Dataset

Tags: python, dataset

I am working on a neural network(Variational Autoencoder) to separate music instruments I don't know how to organize my data I have a folder full of spectrograms of the songs as a mix and the spectrograms of each instrument .. I am so new to coding so I don't know how to organize them. I would really appreciate if someone send me a sample code .. Maybe I can put the instr's path in a dict or something. 
I am working with python